# How do I pass this information to print it out in another document? PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am having trouble echoing row data within the page I want to print it out to.

My function works, but only echoes the information because it is local (within the same function).

I'm trying to get this function to echo the database's information to another .php file (same program).

```
public function findByUsername($username) {
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM events WHERE username=? ';
    $statement = DatabaseHelper::runQuery($this->connection, $sql, Array($username));
    while ($row = $statement->fetch()) {
        echo $row['username'] . "<br />";
        echo $row['date'] . "<br />";
       
    }
}
```

Here is the part of the other file I need to print the information from the function to:

```
<?php
if (isset($_SESSION["username"])) {
    $eventDAO = new EventDAO($connection);
    $event = $eventDAO->findByUsername($_SESSION["username"]);
    foreach((array)$event as $e) {
        echo $e->getUsername() . ' ' . $e->getDate() . '<br>';
    }
}
?>
```

I'm trying to output the username/date.
Not 100% on this concept.

Comment: There are many ways to pass data between scripts of the same app, and all depends on app's structure. As we don't know it we can not advice what will be best in your case.

Comment: Welcome at StackOverflow. Please update your question with more details or it will be closed and/or downvoted. Please read about [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I'm not sure what I can add. Other than code but I think it may be redundant. It's an OOP PHP program using mysql and PDO. Sorry, do you need more code?

Comment: Using words *other* and *another* scripts will not let us to guess how they are connected, which includes which (if at all) etc. I don't know how many parts of code are required to be able to analyse it, you just need to describe is good enough, that anybody else will have no doubts what are you asking about. At the moment it's impossible, sorry.

Comment: Take a look at [PHP Sessions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php)

Answer (score 0):

If you're simply trying to output username/date from one file to another, try using sessions.

```
public function findByUsername($username) {
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM events WHERE username=? ';
$statement = DatabaseHelper::runQuery($this->connection, $sql, Array($username));
while ($row = $statement->fetch()) {
    echo $row['username'] . "<br />";
    echo $row['date'] . "<br />";
    $_SESSION['getuname'] = $row['username'];
    $_SESSION['getdate'] = $row['date'];
 }
}
```

You can then output the information on another php file simply by echoing it out.

```
echo "Username is ". $_SESSION['getuname'];
```

Comment: Thank you that works. BUT - I have multiple instances for each username. So each username has multiple dates. The echo in your second piece of code is only getting it once. I'm not sure what kind of loop to work into it to get all the dates displayed for one user.

Comment: Okay, I'm not exactly getting your question, but you can try putting the entire row in a session variable, e.g. $_SESSION['getrow'] = $row; and then using a foreach loop to get multiple values, e.g. foreach ($row as $key => $value) {echo $value."<br/>";} Hope this helps!